# export PMML Model

Tags: user-interface, pmml

I have a PMML file generated with SPSS's neural networks.

in this model i have 20 predictors, the hidden layer, and a binary result.

Now, i can run this model as many times as i want at home, but i really want to export it for the hospital's pc with a simple interface, like a small window where to enter the 20 predictors and a field displaying the prediction's value.

i'm really really new to the field, i really appreciate any help you can provide.

I have tried googling but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to get this done.

Comment: What field are you *really really new to* - PMML? building user interfaces? programming in general? If we know what you can and can't do then we may be able to help. Would it be OK to deploy your model as a web application, where the code runs on a server which users access through their web browser, or does it have to be installed on the user's PC for standalone use?

Comment: would it be ok to build a web app, but i don't really know what is the most newbie friendly way to approach this. 
I have never made a web app, nor do i know how to make a server interact with a pmml model

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer because I'm still not clear on what your skill set is. If you know how to build desktop apps, look for a PMML evaluation (or 'scoring') library for your language(s) and see if it can work with your model. If you don't know enough programming to build a desktop app, ask the SPSS community how to best deploy a model in a simple web interface (but remember that IBM have applied the 'SPSS' name to several different products). If you can code but can't find a suitable PMML evaluator, try rebuilding your model using a neural network library for your language?